# Differentiating between const references to immutable vs. mutable objects

Tags: c++

Is there any accepted way in C++ to differentiate between const references to immutable objects vs. mutable ones?

e.g.

```
class DataBuffer {
   // ...
};

class Params {
   // ...
};

class C {
public:
    // Given references must be valid during instance lifetime.
    C(const Params& immutableParameters, const DataBuffer& mutableDataBuffer) :
        m_immutableParameters{immutableParameters},
        m_mutableDataBuffer{mutableDataBuffer}
    {
    }

    void processBuffer();
private:
    const Params& m_immutableParameters;
    const DataBuffer& m_mutableDataBuffer;
};
```

Here the semantic difference is given just in the names.

The problem is that `const&` instance variables only let you know the object won't be modified by the instance. There is no distinction in the interface whether or not they may be modified elsewhere, which I think is a useful feature to be able to describe in the interface.

Expressing this through the type-system would help make interfaces clearer, allow the compiler to catch errors (e.g. accidentally modifying parameters handed to a `C` instance, outside of the instance, in the example above), and possibly help with compiler optimizations.

Assuming that the answer is that the distinction isn't possible in C++, maybe there is something close which can be achieved with some templates magic?

Comment: If you don't want programmers to be able to change a variable, then mark it `const`. I don't really understand your question though.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Assume C is given, and you want to describe its interface. In some cases, you may want to force users of the class to pass in a const reference to an immutable object, since that is, semantically, the interface which the class expects.

Comment: When class `C` receives a `const T&` parameter, it can only assume he has a ready only access to an object for the lifetime of the function being executed (in this case the constructor). Therefore I think it is flawed to copy those references in members of C. maybe the example is just incorrect.

Comment: @UmNyobe So, regardless of the original question, are you saying that it's illegal (UB?) in C++ to store const references parameters, received in a ctor, in instance variables? I certainly don't know of this limitation.

Comment: I didn't say illegal nor UB, just flawed design. Here the class C somehow knows that the objects referred by Parameters and DataBuffer  will be valid until its destruction.

Comment: @UmNyobe I see what you meant now. Yes, I do make the assumption that the references will be valid during the `C` instance's lifetime.

Comment: @Danra: "*help make interfaces clearer*" Since the language makes no distinction between the two cases, it makes your interface *less* clear, as you have to use hackery to prevent accidental calling of the function with a mutable object. Also, it's so easily worked around (`as_const`) that users will not understand what you were trying to accomplish. "*possibly help with compiler optimizations*" The compiler does not recognize a difference between an immutable reference and a "currently-`const`" mutable one. So no optimization is possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas "The compiler does not recognize a difference between an immutable reference and a... mutable one" I know, that's the example I posted above. The question is if there is some (sane) way to achieve the distinction, since it would make the interface more expressive of the intent.

Comment: @Danra: "it would make the interface more expressive of the intent" Look at Rakete's answer. Does that look to you "expressive of the intent" that this function will only take truly immutable objects? No. To the reader, it is not at all clear why that template constructor is deleted; you'd need a comment or something explaining what that syntax is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree that specific answer doesn't express the intent well. (Though it might be possible to hide the implementation somehow with template magic that *would* be expressive in the interface).

Comment: I can envision `std::immutable<T>` which duplicates all the statics & fields of T as const and all the const / statics, the latter only when it doesn't modify any static/non-static member.

Comment: I've read this question, all comments and the followup question. And I still don't understand how `const DataBuffer& mutableDataBuffer` could make any sense. Or do you mean `const MutableDataBuffer& immutableDataBuffer`?

Comment: Perhaps I finally get what you mean. You are concerned that outside code may modify the buffer even though `C` views it as `const` all the time?

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: If you have a `const DataBuffer& mutableDataBuffer`, then anyone with a non-const reference can modify the data, and you'd have a read-only view to their changes. With `const Params& m_immutableParameters;`, the class _itself_ is immutible, so you know outsiders _cannot_ modify that object.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thank you, I understand now. Somehow, this simple explanation just didn't cross my mind. Oh well :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Immutability is *not* part of the C++ type system. As such, you cannot differentiate between immutable objects and mutable ones. And even if you could, `std::as_const` will *always* ruin your attempt to do so.

If you are writing an interface that requires immutability of objects, the easiest way to handle this is to invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering: "We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection." So make immutability *part* of the type system. For example (FYI: uses some small C++17 library stuff):

```
template<typename T>
class immutable
{
public:
  template<typename ...Args>
  immutable(std::in_place_t, Args &&...args) t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

  immutable() = default;
  ~immutable() = default;

  immutable(const immutable &) = default;
  //Not moveable.
  immutable(immutable &&) = delete;

  //Not assignable.
  immutable operator=(const immutable &) = delete;
  immutable operator=(immutable &&) = delete;

  const T* operator->() const {return &t;}
  const T& operator*() const {return t;}

private:
  const T t;
};
```

With this type, the internal `T` will be immutable *regardless* of how the user declares their `immutable<T>`. Your `C` class should now take an `immutable<Params>` by `const&`. And since `immutable<T>` cannot be constructed from a copy or move of an existing `T`, the user is forced to use `immutable<Params>` whenever they want to pass that as a parameter.

Of course, your biggest danger is that they'll pass a temporary. But that was a problem you already needed to solve.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if this will allow the compiler make optimizations which aren't possible with a regular const& parameter. My guess is it would, since just from looking at the parameter it can tell the inner t cannot be changed by outside code.

Comment: @Danra: probably there are no optimisations that are made on the back of this.  The compiler already assumes that data isn't going to be changed by other code unless it is explicitly told that it can be (see for instance all the problems of using `volatile` in multi-threaded code, which means values can be changed by another thread, and the compiler still optimises to incorrect code!)

Comment: @dave AFAIK that's plain wrong. If you store a plain const reference, then most of the times when you access it (say each time you first access it within a new method call) the compiler must assume some other unrelated code which has a non const reference to the object might have changed the object, therefore the object must be dereferenced.

Comment: @Danra: And how far would that extend? After all, you have to use `*` or `->` to get at the object, which ultimately leads to a reference (or `this` pointer). Can every `const` member function of `T` assume that it will be invoked on an immutable object? No. After lots of inlining, the compiler might be able to trace the pointer or reference back to the `immutable`. But unless it inlined the functions you use that `T` with, then it won't *know* that the `T` is immutable.

Comment: @NicolBolas It makes sense that inlining would be required to make use of the knowledge that the object is const. Either inlining of the methods called on the object, *or* inlining of a function which accesses instance variables of the object (either directly or via inlined methods) - imagine this function being called in a loop 100 times, the fetched instance variables values' could be cached instead of re-fetched each time.

Comment: Deleting the move doesn't make sense - it prevents copying from rvalues. You probably want to leave it undeclared.

Comment: @T.C.: I'm not sure if one would actually want that. In C++17, prvalues will not attempt invoke a move constructor, and I *want* to see a compile error if you do `immutable<T>(std::move(some_immutable))`.

Comment: @NicolBolas How about `immutable<T> f() { immutable<T> ret{...}; return ret; }`? NRVO isn't covered by guaranteed elision.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the reason, but here's how you can do it:

```
struct C {
   template<typename T, typename T2>
   C(T&&, const T2&&) = delete;

   C(const Params&, const DataBuffer&) { /*...*/ }
};
```

By declaring a constructor that takes any argument by non-const reference, it will always be a better match than the constructor taking `const&`, as a cv-qualifier doesn't have to be added.

The `const&` constructor is a better match when passing a `const` parameters, as the cv-qualifier doesn't have to be removed.

```
DataBuffer db;

const Params cp;
C c{ cp, db }; // ok, second constructor call is chosen

Params p;
C c2{ p, db }; // error, constructor is deleted
```

Due note that, as [@IgorTandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792765/differentiating-between-const-references-to-immutable-vs-mutable-objects/41792910?noredirect=1#comment70774013_41792910), you can break your requirement easily:

```
Params pa;
const Params& ref_pa = pa;
C c3{ ref_pa, db }; // ok, but shouldn't compile.
```

Comment: Could probably still be fooled with something like `DataBuffer db; const DataBuffer& dbRef = db; C c(..., dbRef);`. Perhaps not likely to happen deliberately, but a function that itself takes a const ref can pass it along to `C`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik True, but there is no way to prevent such use. Although, if someone does this, they probably *want* to break the rules :)

Comment: C++17's `std::as_const` function will make it much easier to break such code.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I thought I explained the reason already :) - to describe C's interface better. Upvoted, interesting. Could you please edit the answer to match the question? Just the first parameter is supposed to be forced immutable.

Comment: @Danra I still don't understand *why* you would want to do this :) OK, sorry. Forgot than the second one doesn't have to be `const` :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: Now it won't trigger correctly, since the 1-argument constructor won't try to be called.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Because expressive interfaces are important. I listed some benefits of being able to do this at the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is not a const reference, but a const object. Value semantics solve your problem. Nobody can modify a const object. While a reference is only const where it is marked const, because the referenced object may not be const. Take that for example :

```
int a;

int const& b = a;

// b = 4; <-- not compiling, the reference is const
```

Above, `a` is int, and `b` is a reference to const int. While `a` is not const, the language permit the reference to const to be bound on a non const object. So it's a reference to const object that is bound to a mutable object. The type system won't allow you to modify the mutable object through the reference, because it may have been bound to a const object. In our case it isn't, but the tribe don't change. However, even declaration of a reference to const won't change the original declaration. The int `a` is still a mutable object. `a` may still change value:

```
a = 7;
```

This is valid, whatever references or other kind of variables have been declared. A variable declared as `int` (no `const`) can change, and *nothing* can prevent it from changing. Heck, even another program like cheat engine can change the value of a mutable variable. Even if you had rules in the language to guarantee that it won't be modified, there is *nothing* they will prevent the mutable variable from changing values. In any language. In machine language, a mutable value is permitted to change. However, maybe some API of the operating system can help you change the mutability of memory regions.

---

What can you do to solve this problem now?

If you want to be 100% sure an object won't be modified, you must have immutable data. You usually declare immutable objects with the `const` keyword :

```
const int a = 8;

int const& b = a;

// a cannot change, and b is guaranteed to be equal to 8 at this point.
```

If you don't want `a` to be immutable and still guarantee `b` to not change, use values instead of references :

```
int a = 8;

const int b = a;

a = 9;

// The value of b is still 8, and is guaranteed to not change.
```

Here, value sematic can help you have what you want.

Then const reference are there for what? There are there to express what you are going to do with the reference, and help enforce what can change *where*.

---

As the question has been further clarified, no there is no way to determine if the reference has been bound to a mutable or immutable object in the first place. There is, however, some tricks you can have to differentiate the mutability.

You see, if you want more information about the mutability to be passed along with the instance, you can store that information in the type.

```
template<typename T, bool mut>
struct maybe_immutable : T {
    using T::T;
    static constexpr auto mutable = mut;
};

// v--- you must sync them --v
const maybe_immutable<int, false> obj;
```

This is the most simple way to implement it, but a naive one too. The contained data will be conditionally immutable, but it forces you to sync template parameter and constness. However, the solution allows you to do this :

```
template<typename T>
void do_something(const T& object) {
    if(object.mutable) {
        // initially mutable
    } else {
        // initially const
    }
}
```

Comment: That's all clear. The question was whether there is a way to differentiate between const references to const (immutable) objects and const references to mutable objects.

Comment: @Danra there is a solution that rudimentary do what you want. See my edits.

Answer (score 4):

As previous answers, C++ doesn't have the concept of "immutable". @Rakete1111 gave you the answer I would have used. However, Visual Studio will put global const variable in .rdata segment, where other variables will go to .data. The .rdata segment will generate a fault when trying to write.

If you need a run time test whether an object is read only, use a signal handler, like this:

```
#include <csignal>
const int l_ci = 42;
int l_i = 43;

class AV {};
void segv_handler(int signal) {
    throw AV{};
}

template <typename T>
bool is_mutable(const T& t)
{
    T* pt = const_cast<int*>(&t);

    try {
        *pt = T();
    }
    catch (AV av) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void test_const()
{
    auto prev_handler = std::signal(SIGSEGV, segv_handler);
    is_mutable(l_i);
    is_mutable(l_ci);
}
```

Comment: You should delete your answer before someone uses it.
Here is what's wrong with it:
- signal handler do not execute in the same context as your is_mutable function. You catch won't catch anything.
- I'm pretty sure the signal handler doesn't work well with the exception mechanism (I think there are some flags to try to make it work, but that is a grey area.)
- Using your is_mutable function on mutable data reset the value to 0.
- You use templates but you could just use ints as your function doesn't work with anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand you question correct it is not as explicit as so to say "D language" but with const r-value references you can make immutable parameters.

What I understand from immutable is forexample

```
void foo ( const int&&  immutableVar );
foo(4);-> is ok 
int a = 5;
foo(a);->is not ok
```

Comment: But then again, `const int b = 5; foo(b)` is also illegal.