# Forcing class instances to be const

Tags: c++

Is there any way to force to only allow const instances of class to be instantiated, and have non-const instances be detected as an error by the compiler?

Comment: No, not that I know of. It [might help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to explain *why* you need to do this.

Comment: If the class has only const member functions, then you don't need this feature. If it has non-const member functions, then they would become obsolete by such a feature. What is it that you really try to accomplish?

Comment: My current motivation is a possible method for solving http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792765/differentiating-between-const-references-to-immutable-vs-mutable-objects.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Interesting, is there any generic way to take an existing class, and "constify" it by removing all non-const functionality?

Comment: @Danra: No. How could that possibly work? What would you do about the **implementation** of a function like `void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Nothing, this method shouldn't be accessible for instances of the "consitified" class, just as it isn't accessible for const instances of the original class.

Comment: @Danra: Then I don't get it, sorry. `C const` *is* the way to create a type which is exactly like `C` minus its non-const member functions. In other words, `C const` does "constify" `C`.

Comment: @Danra "is there any generic way to take an existing class, and "constify" it by removing all non-const functionality?" - yes, by editing the source text.

Comment: @ChristianHackl it constifies the instance, not the class. I believe there is value in being able to give a new name to the "constified C" class. For example, given a `const&` to an instance of the "constified" class, you can be certain that no modifications are possible the object you're referencing; not just by your own code which uses the references, but by any other code which references the same object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792765/differentiating-between-const-references-to-immutable-vs-mutable-objects for more details on a possible use case.

Comment: @ChristianHackl e.g. it would be nice to have something like `class D : public const C {}`

Comment: @chris That's nice. Unfortunately, while it does answer the question (welcome to post it as an answer and I'll accept) it doesn't actually express what I was looking for; I wanted to be able to express that a `const ConstT&` parameter to a method is a reference to an immutable object. Unfortunately, it just forces the parameter to be immutable during in the method's implementation, as usual per const parameters.

Comment: @Danra: Your `D` class would be useless. Everyone else could still just declare their variables `C`. You could choose to use `D` in your own code, for example by declaring a function `f(D& obj)` to make sure that you do not accidentally modify `obj`. But that's exactly what `C const` accomplishes! So you'd make the function `f(C const& obj)`. What do I miss?

Comment: @ChristianHackl See my original motivation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792765/differentiating-between-const-references-to-immutable-vs-mutable-objects for why such a class wouldn't be useless (at least, if the semantics for using D in a function parameter would be different than writing "const C", which just forces the function implementation to treat C as immutable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any generic way to take an existing class, and "constify" it by removing all non-const functionality?

One possible workaround is to create a wrapper class that holds an instance of the class and only gives access to a `const` reference to it.

```
template<class T>
class Immutable {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Immutable(Args&&... args) : instance(forward<Args>(args)...) {
    }
    operator const T&() {
        return instance;
    }
    const T& get() const {
        return instance;
    }
private:
    Immutable& operator=(const Immutable& other) = delete;
    T instance;
};
```

Suppose you have a mutable class `Class`:

```
class Class {
public:
    Class() : m_value(0) {
    }
    Class(const Class& other) : m_value(other.m_value) {
    }
    Class(int value) : m_value(value) {
    }
    Class(int x, int y) : m_value(x + y) {
    }
    void change(int value) {
        m_value = value;
    }
    int value() const {
        return m_value;
    }
private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Here is how `Immutable<Class>` can be used:

```
void functionTakingConstReference(const Class& x) {
}

void functionTakingNonConstReference(Class& x) {
}

void functionTakingImmutableClass(Immutable<Class>& x) {
}

void functionTakingValue(Class x) {
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Any constructor of Class can also be used with Immutable<Class>.
    Immutable<Class> a;
    Immutable<Class> b(1);
    Immutable<Class> c(2, 3);
    Immutable<Class> d(c);

    // Compiles and works as expected.
    functionTakingConstReference(a);
    functionTakingImmutableClass(a);
    functionTakingValue(a);
    cout << a.get().value() << endl;

    // Doesn't compile because operator= is deleted.
    // b = a;


    // Doesn't compile because "change" is a non-const method.
    // a.get().change(4);


    // Doesn't compile because the function takes a non-const reference to Class as an argument.
    // functionTakingNonConstReference(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, and similar to an answer to a related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/41793446/125997

Comment: One could still do `Class e = a;`, no?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, a `Class` object can be copy-initialized with an `Immutable<Class>` object, similarly to how an `Immutable<Class>` variable can passed to `functionTakingConstReference(const Class& x)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to force to only allow const instances of class to be instantiated, and have non-const instances be detected as an error by the compiler?

No.

But you can declare all members as const. Then both const and non-const instances would behave largely in the same way and it shouldn't matter whether the instances are const.

Comment: Not really. `const` member functions can be called from non-const instances. But the other way around would work quite well.

Comment: @Rakete1111 if there are no non-const functions, then there is no way to call them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an immutable class. An easy way to get immutability is to declare all member variables as `const`. This way you ensure that the state of your objects will not change after construction. 
This guarantee is independent of whether your object is `const` and even if you have `non-const` member functions for that class.
For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int id, double value) : m_id(id), m_value(value) { }
    int Id() const { return m_id; }
    double Value() const { return m_value; }

private:
    const int m_id;
    const double m_value;
};
```

Another way you could generate an immutable object of any type is through a template class. Something like this:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int id, double value) : m_id(id), m_value(value) { }
    int Id() const { return m_id; }
    double Value() const { return m_value; }
    void SetId(int id) { m_id = id; }

private:
    int m_id;
    double m_value;
};

template<typename T>
class MyImmutable
{
public:
    const T m_obj;

    MyImmutable(const T& obj) : m_obj(obj)
    { }
};



int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    Foo a(1,2.0);
    Bar x(2,3.0);
    MyImmutable<Bar> y(x);
    cout << "a.id    = " << a.Id() << endl;
    cout << "a.value = " << a.Value() << endl;

    cout << "y.id    = " << y.m_obj.Id() << endl;
    cout << "y.value = " << y.m_obj.Value() << endl;

    y.m_obj.SetId(2); // calling non-const member throws an error.

    return 0;
}
```