# Simplifying the use of ref qualifiers in c++20

Tags: c++, c++17, ref-qualifier

```
#include <string>

struct S
{
    std::string s_;

    std::string_view get() const &
    {
        return s_;
    }

    std::string_view get() const && = delete;
};

//  I can't change this
struct T
{
    T(std::string_view const sv);  //  does something safe with sv
};

//  I can't change this
void f(std::string_view const &);

void g()
{
    f(S{}.get());  //  should compile
    T t(S{}.get());  //  should compile
    std::string_view sv = S{}.get();  //  should not compile
}
```

Is there way to use ref qualifiers without hindering usability as in the case above?  In essence, it should prevent unsafe usage, but allow safe usage.  I can wrap `f` which does this, but it is unnecessary verbosity

Comment: you should include the compiler error message you do get from the code in the question

Comment: I don't believe so. `S{}.get()` is either allowed or not. *Where* it's used makes no difference.

Comment: one approach is to return a proxy that can be converted to the actual desired type, but I dont see how it can be `//  should compile` and at the same time `//  should not compile`

Comment: `std::string_view const & get() const && = delete;` means that you don't want `S{}.get()` to be compiled. But then your code `f(S{}.get());  //  should compile` contradicts this.

Comment: Possibly related: [Forcing class instances to be const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41793183/580083).

Comment: It is a contradiction.  But is there a way to allow the safe usage while disallowing unsafe usage?  Wrapper classes and functions do the trick, but was trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to use ref qualifiers without hindering usability as in the case above?

No, because when you wrote `std::string_view get() const && = delete;` you're essentially(**implicitly**) saying that `S{}.get()` should not be compiled. But then later in the code you're writing `f(S{}.get());  //  should compile` which contradicts the above code.

Basically, whether or not `S{}.get()` can be used is decided by the presence of the `std::string_view get() const && = delete;`.

Comment: But is there a way to differentiate the 2 types of usage?  I guess not.  I'll go with a wrapper for `f`

Comment: @zrb Basically, `S{}.get()` follow the same rule that it is not allowed in any evaluated context because you've written `std::string_view get() const && = delete;`. Not possible to differentiate.